# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I cannot figure out where this syntax error is coming from. It shows as index.html:2 in my console but that doesn't seem right.

Here is my javascript:

```
$('#add').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newItem = document.momList.newItem.value;
    if (newItem) {
        var $listItem = $('<li id="' + newItem + '"><button class="delete" onclick="removeListItem("' + newItem + '");">X</button></li>');
        var $item = $('<span class="item">').text(newItem);
        $listItem.append($item);
        $('#list').append($listItem);
    }
});

function removeListItem(itemID) {
    var el = document.getElementById(itemID);
    el.remove();
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mother's Shopping List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Mother's Shopping List</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form name="momList">
            <input id="newItem" type="text" required>
            <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" class="add">
        </form>
        <div class="shoppingList">
            <ul id="list" class="shoppingList"></ul>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a new list item whenever the add button is clicked. Each list item had a delete button that I want to remove that list item when clicked. I can't get the remove buttons to work.

Comment: What line does it say the error is coming from?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle

Comment: in my devtools console on chrome it says the error is coming from index.html:2

also i've never used a jsfiddle

Comment: @DrewNauman we have no idea where line 2 begins. Please edit your post and clarify **what line line number 2 is**

Comment: heres a JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rzq8wgvq/

Comment: The problem is somewhere else [because that code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/vjkjcrcd/1/)

Comment: It's probably a missing `)` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an event handler that is bound to buttons outside of html attributes:

```
$('#add').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newItem = document.momList.newItem.value;
    if (newItem) {
        var $listItem = $('<li id="' + newItem + '"><button class="delete">X</button></li>');
        var $item = $('<span class="item">').text(newItem);
        $listItem.append($item);
        $('#list').append($listItem);
    }
});

$(document).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    console.log("im here");
    var el = $(e.target).parent();
    el.remove();
});
```

This prevents issues like the double quote problem and is a cleaner solution because of keeping JavaScript out of html.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the quotes cause a problem in the onclick. use \' to add an escaped ' in lieu of the quotations for the onclick and it should work fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/5nnvu7vn/3/

```
$('#add').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newItem = document.momList.newItem.value;
    if (newItem) {
        var $listItem = $('<li id="' + newItem + '"><button class="delete" onclick="removeListItem(\'' + newItem + '\');">X</button></li>');
        var $item = $('<span class="item">').text(newItem);
        $listItem.append($item);
        $('#list').append($listItem);
    }
});

function removeListItem(itemID) {
    var el = document.getElementById(itemID);
    el.remove();
}
```

Comment: For sure! The double quotes close the "onclick" attribute, making it actually empty.